# May2015 CU Update Broke My Search. Help

Tags: 2013, search, cumulative-update

I recently applied May 2015 CU Update now my crawl pages are getting error messages

I receive following error while i open the page

"The service implementation object was not initialized or is not available"

IN SharePoint logs this is what i get

```
Application error when access /_admin/search/CrawlLogContentSources.aspx, Error=The service implementation object was not initialized or is not available.  Server stack trace:  
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) 
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:  
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchCentralAdminPageBase.ErrorHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchCentralAdminPageBase.OnError(EventArgs e) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Right after this alert i also get following SQL Alerts:

```
A database error occurred. Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Code: 64 occurred 0 time(s) Description: Error ordinal: 1 Message: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.), Class: 20, Number: 64, State: 0 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)

at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()

at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()

at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()

at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)

at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)

at Microsoft.Office.Server.Data.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData, Boolean retryForDeadLock)

at Microsoft.Office.Server.Data.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)

at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.ManagedSqlSession.ExecuteReader()
```

I then contacted SQl team and asked if any SQL roles or permissions were revoked, but everything looks good. Search Crawl Service Account  has SPSearchDBAdmin and SPDataaccess on all Search related DB's

Comment: from review upgrade status page, is any database complaing about the update required?

Comment: All Database Status are No Action Required and Upgrade Status page dont have any error too

Comment: How did it work out for you? Did you find any solution? I have not yet applied the CU but plan to do so.

Comment: working with microsoft, looks like it corrupted my search service application. We deleted service applciation proxy and created a new one and created a new endpoint for search and cleared the config cache and restarted IIS in all servers. Not resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found re-creating the search service fixed this - however the issue came back a few times and re-creating the search service was some what frustrating so I reset the search index in CA and that fixed it again. Shall see if it comes back!